# Magento 2 New Module not appearing in admin Disable Modules Output

Tags: magento-2.1, module, configuration

I am new to M2, and just adding a new module to a local devbox environment using PhpStorm IDE.  I've created the module several ways, rather, several modules, each a different way:

- [Magento 2 Code Generator](https://github.com/staempfli/magento2-code-generator)
- [Pestle](https://github.com/astorm/pestle)
- [Magicento 2](http://magicento.com/)

Each time, after I create the module I run:

`bin/magento module:status`

The module appears as a disabled module, great!

I run: `bin/magento module:enable Newvendor_Newmodule`

If I rerun `module:status` it now appears as enabled

I run: `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

So far so good, but when I look in admin Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced  the module is NOT in the list... what?

I have cleared cache (several times), disabled the modules, re-enabled them, created new ones... I cannot figure out why they do not appear in admin, but the magento CI "sees" them?

I noticed this while I was trying to debug a simple [M2 Frontend Controller Tutorial from Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/).  It seems like I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what?

Example of Module contents (inside of app/code/Vendor/Testmodule/)

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Testmodule',
__DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Testmodule" setup_version="0.0.1" >
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally realized what was causing this issue... it is sync related and is documented in this devbox issue https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web/issues/79

I tried the solution by @raybogman and that resolved it.  I did have to clean out the other files in the .unison directory before I made the watch = false change (don't delete the .prf file)